# Floated Div over Absolute Positioned Div

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-float

I am trying to achieve this:
An image that is 1000px wide and 350px tall on the left of the screen. An email capture that is on the right of the screen. I want the email div to sit over part of the image at 1024px, 1200px,etc, but when the screen is expanded(or viewed on larger screens), I want the two to drift apart and then stop at a max-width. I believe I have achieved this part of the process.

My second concern is when the screen gets smaller than 1024, I'd like the email capture to fall below the image.

I have this setup now as an absolute positioned image and a floating div going over it with a max width for the containing div that holds the two. But with the absolute placement, the floating div does not slide below the absolute placed image right away, but sort of jerks back and forth between left and right side of screen and finally ends up on top of the image...

http://new.healthcareexcellence.org/

Comment: look into CSS media queries for what you are trying to achieve www.mediaqueri.es

Answer (score 0):

The `position: absolute;` on the image container `.home-featured-left` is the culprit.

You just need to 'disable' the absolute positioning when it's not required (once you hit small screen sizes). There are many ways you could go about it, but the easiest way is to just add the following:

```
.home-featured-left {
    position: static;
}
```

into your media query for small screen sizes: `@media only screen and (max-width: 960px)`

Comment: Apologises Matt, I meant  `position: static;`. I updated this now in my answer.

Setting it to static will set the position style back to the default (static is the default if position hasn't been defined yet). Alternatively, `position: relative;` would also work.